# SSH from one vm to another vm hosted on vagrant

Tags: virtualbox

I am trying to create an ssh connection from one VM (ubuntu 16.04) to another VM (same installed with ubuntu 16.04).

I just spawn these two machines by the default command of vagrant and I am using ubuntu/xenial64 & bento/ubuntu-16.04 machine. When I am checking the ifconfig command both machines is giving me the same IP address.

Any clue how to ssh from one machine to another machine.

I don't find any relevant page for this.

VM1 Details:

```
vagrant@ubuntu-xenial:~$ ip addr show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever – JYOTI PRAKASH MALLICK 7 hours ago

2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 02:bb:f4:57:e9:87 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global enp0s3
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::bb:f4ff:fe57:e987/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

VM2 Details:

```
vagrant@vagrant:~$ ip addr shoow
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:a0:91:3b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global eth0
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fea0:913b/64 scope link
        valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Did you check if NICs have different mac addresses?

Comment: Can you include the output of `ip addr show`? How do you have the network configured for the VMs?

Comment: Sure, adding the output here

Comment: @JYOTIPRAKASHMALLICK Please show the command and output **as text**, formatted as a code block instead of using screenshots.

Comment: @Bodo please check the above output

Comment: You have to configure the network, see e.g. https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/networking/private_network.html

Comment: Thanks and let me try